# XCode: framework not found

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks

I tried to remove framework and re-add it. Tried to specify the direct path to it in Build Phases. But it still does not work.

[image: framework tree]
[image]
[image: the error]

Comment: What do you have set for FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS in build settings?

Comment: @wilc0 you can see that in the second screenshot. There is a project dir and a couple of my attempts to indicate a direct path to the framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that framework and its Header file had different names.
It was (for example): framework - FoodCourtDB.framework, header - FoodCourt.h ;
It become: FoodCourt.framework, FoodCourt.h